# Python resturant management system how to add inventory reciept

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

The code given below is intended to calculate the bill of items entered by the cashier in the entry widget **order_raw**, to do so i have placed **sum=0** before defining a function and then made the increment to the sum, but still my program doesn't calculate the total bill.It keeps giving me zero.Currently there is no error in my code.

```
from tkinter import *
order=[]
window=Tk()
order_raw=Entry(window)
order_raw.pack()
global bill
bill=0
def totalbill():
    global bill
    global billvar
    order.append(order_raw.get())
    if order_raw.get()=="burger":
        bill=bill+200
    if order_raw.get()=="fries":
        bill=bill+200
    print(bill)
billvar=StringVar(value=bill)
checkout=Button(window, text="total", command=totalbill)
checkout.pack()
total=Entry(window, textvariable=billvar)
total.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

then i shifted the **StringVar** inside to the function where the vriable sum is modified.But then it gives my an error, below is the code and its error.

```
from tkinter import *
order=[]
window=Tk()
order_raw=Entry(window)
order_raw.pack()
global bill
bill=0
def totalbill():
    global bill
    global billvar
    order.append(order_raw.get())
    if order_raw.get()=="burger":
        bill=bill+200
    if order_raw.get()=="fries":
        bill=bill+200
    print(bill)
    billvar=StringVar(value=bill)
checkout=Button(window, text="total", command=totalbill)
checkout.pack()
total=Entry(window, textvariable=billvar)
total.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

**error**

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/umerk/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 20, in <module>
    total=Entry(window, textvariable=billvar)
NameError: name 'billvar' is not defined
```

Comment: Be careful! `list` is a built-in type in Python. You are shadowing it. Give this variable another name

Comment: but it wont reolve the main issue

Comment: No, that's irrelevant. Actually, from your question it is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve, and what is the problem you have encountered. Your code doesn't throw any errors. And there is too much irrelevant information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @UmerNaeem If it did, it would've been an _answer_ as opposed to a comment.

Comment: how about now??? can you understand it now??

Comment: Delete `sumv` from `def addfunct(sumv):` and insert `global sumv` after `def addfunct():`. And tell me if you get the expected result

Comment: nopes it didnt, i was wandering if we could introduce a new IntVar and then in the entry use text variable but its giving the same old value, i hope you understand

Comment: i hope you understand it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the bottom entry in the first code snippet, just add:

```
billvar.set(bill)
```

as the last line in your `totalbill`. See below examples as well.

---

Example with [variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and `Entry`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def sum_cb():
    global item, sum_var

    if item.get() == "burger":
        sum_var.set(sum_var.get() + 30)

    elif item.get() == "fries":
        sum_var.set(sum_var.get() + 10)

root = tk.Tk()
item = tk.Entry(root)
sum_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
sum_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sum_var)
sum_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Sum", command=sum_cb)

item.pack()
sum_btn.pack()
sum_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Here's a minimal example of a GUI that calculates the sum of the numbers entered and displays them as button text:

```
import tkinter as tk

def sum_cb():
    global sum_btn, item

    if item.get() == "burger":
        sum_btn['text'] = int(sum_btn['text']) + 30

    elif item.get() == "fries":
        sum_btn['text'] = int(sum_btn['text']) + 10

root = tk.Tk()
item = tk.Entry(root)
sum_btn = tk.Button(root, text=0, command=sum_cb)

item.pack()
sum_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Display in an additional [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) instead of `Button` text:

```
import tkinter as tk

def sum_cb():
    global item, sum_entry

    cur_sum = int(sum_entry.get())
    sum_entry.delete(0, 'end')

    if item.get() == "burger":
        sum_entry.insert(0, cur_sum + 30)

    elif item.get() == "fries":
        sum_entry.insert(0, cur_sum + 10)

root = tk.Tk()
item = tk.Entry(root)
sum_entry = tk.Entry(root)
sum_entry.insert(0, 0)
sum_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Sum", command=sum_cb)

item.pack()
sum_btn.pack()
sum_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah right, it calculate the sum of numbers, but actually i am trying to enter  a string in  the entry widget, lets supposed "burger" and now i want the program to understand the burger as $30, so in that way when i enter "fries" it adds $10, i hope you understand

Comment: thansk bro, just love you, now just one last thing, now for the entry widget how would you use it, i mean instead of button how would you use entry widget

Comment: @UmerNaeem Added example with a variable class and an entry.